# How to change scale of Sprite in PixiJS without loosing on resolution?

Tags: javascript, textures, sprite, resolution, pixi.js

When I set scale of my Sprite to 0.1 I loose on its texture resolution.

```
export const createSprite = (textureName , position = {x:0,y:0},scale ={x: 0.5 , y:0.5} , anchor = {x:0.5 , y:0.5} ) => {
    const texture = PIXI.Texture.from(textureName);
    const Sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
    Sprite.anchor.copyFrom(anchor);
    Sprite.position.copyFrom(position);
    Sprite.scale.copyFrom(scale);
    return Sprite;
}

 this.view = createSprite('queenW');
 this.view.scale.set(0.1,0.1)
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou7DX.jpg)
How to get with PixiJS similar result as I got when I tried to put that same img into div element with property set to 'background-size: cover'? Like this

```
<body>
    <style>* {padding: 0; margin: 0} #canvas {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
      background-image: url("./pieces/queen/assets/queenW.png");
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    }</style>
    <div id="canvas" margin="10px" > </div>
    
</body>
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBb3l.jpg)

Comment: Please provide example code and screenshots

Comment: I have updated this thread with IMGs and code

Comment: Have you read these: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/24558-down-scaling-quality-loss/?_fromLogin=1 https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/4845 ?